# Como uso LDAP para remover acesso de usuários em java ou procedure oracle?

Tags: java, windows, servidor, openldap, ldap

Dou manutenção no sistema de pessoal da empresa e preciso implementar uma rotina de que quando o colaborador é aposentado ou demitido, ele perde os acessos nas pastas da rede.

Existe um servidor `LDAP` que controla isso, mas não faço a minima ideia de por onde começar. Alguém conhece exemplos disso ou pode me explicar por onde começar?

Comment: Você tem um sistema e deseja atualizar os dados dos usuários desse sistema com o status do usuário dele do LDAP? Se for isso é só você fazer uma rotina para ler o status do usuário no LDAP e atualizar o status do usuário no seu sistema

Comment: Na verdade preciso bloquear o usuário as pastas de rede quando foram demitidos ou aposentados